# Publishing Mapbox styles using V2.1 and above

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to integrate mapbox maps/styles in HTML code. I succeeded in doing so using:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.14.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.14.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHB0ZXNzaWVyMTMiLCJhIjoiMEhrZUZaTSJ9.xU3ECSdq6K3LUkUuE8mZpQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/lptessier13/cin5q5ilo00skctnfgeyrglfc',
    center: [6.08, 46.22],
    zoom: 11
});
```

Unfortunately, I cannot publish my maps/styles using the following:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHB0ZXNzaWVyMTMiLCJhIjoiMEhrZUZaTSJ9.xU3ECSdq6K3LUkUuE8mZpQ';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map','mapbox://styles/lptessier13/cin5q5ilo00skctnfgeyrglfc')
        .setView([6.08, 46.22], 11);
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

I am not yet well versed in coding, but I thought that the problem may be residing in the API (**mapbox-gl-js/v0.14.1** VS **mapbox.js/v2.1.5**)

If necessary, I could add the whole HTML file which is not very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom, you are trying to load a GL style with Leaflet, which uses tiled images, rather than GL styles.... For instance, change `mapbox://styles...` to 
`mabox.streets` and you'll have a basemap (with lat/long flipped), but then you will have to add your points in via L.geoJson().addTo(map) if you want to use mapbox.js over mapbox-gl.js.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If I could ask another question: are there any reasons why I should use one over the other?

Comment: I would say its personal preference. However, Mapbox/Leaflet has a well established community and is thus far, much easier to develop. Whereas GL is still relatively new. I find myself reading their Github issues as much as their docs. But you can make superior (cartographically speaking) maps with GL. Here is a very good primer on GL: https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-gl-js-fundamentals/

Comment: Hi CCantey,

Many thanks once again for your input and help. The webpage you referenced seems to have really useful information. Have a great day!